# How do you create custom Arrowheads in illustrator CC?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cc-2014

I'm trying to create a custom arrowhead in illustrator CC but can't seem to find out how.

Comment: Third result in a google search: http://tv.adobe.com/watch/learn-illustrator-cc/creating-arrowheads/

Comment: Welcome to GD.  You would get better answers from the community if you show effort and what you have tried.  We will try to help you as best as we can but at this moment it would appear you're asking for a tutorial.

Comment: For what it's worth, this seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me. I've used Illustrator professionally since before arrowheads were introduced, and I've always wondered if/how you can make custom ones.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an Adobe Illustrator Help file that gives a method for adding custom arrowheads to Illustrator CC:

http://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/stroke-object.html#customize_arrowheads

Look at the end of the file, in the section "Customize arrowheads" where it says:

> To define custom arrowheads, open the Arrowheads.ai file, which is
>   located under ShowPackageContent\Required\Resources\\ (for
>   Mac) and \Support Files\Required\Resources\\ (for Windows).
>   Follow the instructions in the file to create custom arrowheads.
>
> Place the updated Arrowheads.ai file at: \Plug-ins\
>   and avoid replacing the existing Arrowheads.ai file.

The "tv.adobe.com" link given above is not relevant; it tells you how to make a pattern-brush arrow, but those don't behave like real arrows.

Comment: Hi Margot, and welcome to GD.SE! Thanks for your answer. Do you think you can include some more info in here, in case the link goes down?

Comment: The missing piece here: once edited, you have to create a new symbol definition (Window > Symbols > New).

Comment: March 2018: the file we need to edit has moved to: /Applications/Adobe Illustrator CC 2018/Support Files/Resources/en_US/Arrowheads.ai